# depth maps .bin in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have depth maps which is in .bin format. I want to access in MATLAB.
I found one code here on stackoverflow

```
function [depthImg] = ReadKiectDepthIndivi(loc)
%This function reads in a Kinect depth image from a bin file  
%Input:  
%   loc - location of the bin file  
%Output:    
%   depthImg - depth image  

%Read in the file  
fid = fopen(loc); %read the file in  
[A, count] = fread(fid, 'uint16=>uint16',2); %load and shift  
fclose(fid); %close the stream  

%Convert into structure  
dims = [320 240]; %dims of the depth  

depth = double(A); %convert to double for imaging  

[depthImg.X, depthImg.Y] = meshgrid([1:dims(1)], [1:dims(2)]); %obtain x and y  
depthImg.Z = reshape(depth, dims(1), dims(2))'; %generate depth  
%temp.Z(temp.Z==0)=NaN; % noise clean up (if required)  
end
```

but this code give me error
After converting to double

```
depth = double(A); %convert to double for imaging
```

the size of depth is 26304003x1

```
dims=[320 240]
```

so it gives me error in

```
depthImg.Z = reshape(depth, dims(1), dims(2))
```

Please anyone help me to convert

Comment: clearly your file does not hold a 320-by-240 `uint16` image, but has much more information (pixels). What application created this bin file? do you have access to its format? does it have a header? what is the true size of the underlying image?

Comment: This (.bin) is depth image from Kinect camera. yes the variable have 320*240*N, where N is the number of frames, That's why the size is too large.

Comment: Well, if the size of `depth` is `26304003x1` it can't be reshaped to 320*240*n (I hope you can see why).  You will have to find some documentation specifying how your particular `bin` file was recorded.